# A mess up with printing text in mips

Tags: mips

I'm writing a code that print through a loop "Enter a number" 20 times, and it happens that the text that I want to print after "The Average is" gets messed up like this "ó???ff¦?". Here's the code:

```
     .data
array:       .space 20
outputA:     .asciiz "The Average is:\n" #prints the average
input:       .asciiz "Enter a number:\n" #prints the statement 
avgNum:      .float 0.0
lengthFloat: .float 3.0
const:       .float 0.0             #I did this because you can't use li for float numbers
zero:        .float 0.0
one:         .float 1.0
.text
la   $t9, outputA
lwc1 $f2, lengthFloat
li   $t0, 0                     #counter i
li   $s2, 0                     #counter j
la   $s1, array                 #base address of the array
la   $k1, input                 #Displaying the message (The else part)
li   $t5, 0                     #currentCount for mode
l.s  $f3, const                 #mode value
li   $t6, 0                     #count for mode
l.s  $f14, zero                 #Just a 0
l.s   $f16, one
loop:
    slti $s0, $t0, 20           #Checking if the counter is less than 20
    beq $s0, $zero, print       #if it's greater or equal to 20 exit the loop
    move $a0, $k1
    li $v0, 4     
    syscall

    li $v0, 6                    #Reading a float number
    syscall


    sll   $t1, $t0, 2            #Storing the value in the appropriate place in memory
    add   $t1, $s1, $t1
    swc1  $f0, 0($t1)
    add.s $f1, $f1, $f0

    addi  $t0, $t0, 1            #Adding the counter 1

j loop

print:
#printing avg
   move $a0, $t9
   li   $v0, 4
   syscall

   li $v0, 2
   div.s $f12, $f1, $f2
   syscall
   mov.s $f10, $f12     #Storig the value of average for later use
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single-precision floating-point number is 4 bytes, so 20 floats require 80 bytes of space. You've only reserved 20 bytes of space, so you'll end up overwriting something else. You'll have to change the declaration of `array` to `array:       .space 20*4`

Also, you're dividing the sum by `3.0`, so you're not calculating the average since that would require dividing by `20.0`.